# Why isn't Git listening to my working tree argument?

Tags: git

I am trying to include the working tree in a checkout, like so:

`git checkout --work-tree=/elsewhere`

But Git keeps complaining that I haven't set a working tree, saying `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`.

I'm clearly setting a working tree, so why is Git ignoring the argument?

Answer (score 6):

It should be `git --work-tree=/elsewhere checkout`.

Git is picky about the order of its arguments: `--work-tree` is an argument to Git, *not the Checkout command*, so you have to put the argument before the command. The same goes for any [other arguments Git itself accepts](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/).